# If I mock an object and/or stub a method in my spec, will that mock be used even though it's only called indirectly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mocking, tdd, bdd

I am new to mocking and stubbing, but I think I have a circumstance where their use would be ideal.

In my application, when a user saves a `Product`, an `after_save` callback fires that creates `Publication` instances which cause the product data to be sent to certain 3rd parties via API.

I have a request spec for `Product` that tests my CRUD operations.

If I stub either the API methods or mock the Publication model, will those mocks/stubs be used in my spec even though they are actually called in the `Product` `after_save` callback? I'm confused about this point.

***Update***

I figured I would just do it like this:

```
Publication.any_instance.stub(:publist).and_return(true)
```

And do that at the beginning of my test. That way whatever instance is created would be handled. Is that how it works?

Comment: Can't tell you without code, as it basically depends on whether you stubbed a class , any instance of a class, or a particular instance.

Comment: Thanks, I detailed how I'm doing it now.

Comment: Oh yes, that will do it. Though I's put it inside say context "when callback" do ... end and put all the tests where the stub is required inside that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that stub will do what it says and the publist method on any instance of the publication class will always return true.

Instead of putting it "at the top" though do something like.

```
context 'when there is a publist' do
  Publication.any_instance.stub(:publist).and_return(true)
  it 'should ...' do
    ...
  end
end
```

then if required you can do tests without the stub, or tests where publist returns false in other context blocks and be nice and clear in the spec.